# cassandra thrift long insert - InvalidRequestException(why:(String didn't validate.)

Tags: cassandra

I'm creating dynamic column family and inserting long value by using thrift Api in Cassandra 2.0.7. But its throwing error only for long type. Other types like string , int and byte are working.

```
InvalidRequestException(why:(String didn't validate.) [Monitor][Groups][since] failed validation)                                                                                           
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result$batch_mutate_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:28232)                                                               
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result$batch_mutate_resultStandardScheme.read(Cassandra.java:28218)                                                               
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$batch_mutate_result.read(Cassandra.java:28152)                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.thrift.TServiceClient.receiveBase(TServiceClient.java:78)                                                                                                                 
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.recv_batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1069)                                                                                                  
    at org.apache.cassandra.thrift.Cassandra$Client.batch_mutate(Cassandra.java:1055)                                                                                                       
    at com.sify.beacon.cf.TestGroups.insertColumns(TestGroups.java:588)



CREATE COLUMN FAMILY Groups
WITH comparator = UTF8Type
AND key_validation_class=UTF8Type
AND default_validation_class = UTF8Type;
```

Code :

public ColumnOrSuperColumn createColumnOrSuperColumn(String name,
        long value, long timestamp) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {

```
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(Long.SIZE);
buffer.putLong(value);

Column column = new Column(ByteBuffer.wrap(name.getBytes("utf-8")));
column.setValue(ByteBuffer.wrap(buffer.array()));
column.setTimestamp(timestamp);

ColumnOrSuperColumn c = new ColumnOrSuperColumn();
c.setColumn(column);
return c;
```

}

I need to do any other conversion to resolve this issue?

Please advise me if anyone have idea.

Comment: can you post your column family definition ..........

Comment: Yes your definition is needed to answer. But you will almost certainly find it many times easier to use one of the java clients for Cassandra e.g. the datastax java driver.

Comment: i have added column family definition .please check..

Answer (score 2):

I have removed the default_validation_class while creating the keyspace.Then insert is happening including long values.

Thanks for your support

Answer (score 1):

Please change your

```
default_validation_class = UTF8Type to default_validation_class = LongType
```

It should work.

Comment: I dont think it will resolve the issue. Because i'm creating the column families by dynamically and inserting varies type of values like string ,byte ,int and long.

Comment: Also i have changed as you said. But its throwing exception why because state is string type .                                                 

InvalidRequestException(why:(Expected 8 or 0 byte long (2)) [Monito][Groups][state] failed validation)

Comment: Are you using thrift client or any other client?